# Query with multiple left joins - points column value is incorrect

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

I have the following database structure, and I am trying to run a single query that will show classrooms and how many students are part of the classroom, and how many rewards a classroom has allocated out, as well as how many points allocated to a single classroom (based on the classroom_id column).

Using the query at the very bottom I am trying to collect the 'totalPoints' that a classroom has assigned - based on counting the points column in the classroom_redeemed_codes table and return this as a single integer.

For some reason the values are incorrect for the totalPoints - I am doing something wrong but not sure what...

-- UPDATE --
Here is the sqlfiddle:-
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9f45

My Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `organisation_classrooms` (
  `classroom_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `organisation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `period` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `classroom_bg` int(2) DEFAULT '3',
  `sortby` varchar(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'points',
  `sound` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`classroom_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE organisation_classrooms_myusers (
  `classroom_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
);

CREATE TABLE `classroom_redeemed_codes` (
  `redeemed_code_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `myuser_id` bigint(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ssuser_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `classroom_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `order_product_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `order_product_images_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `date_redeemed` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notified` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `inactive` tinyint(3) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`redeemed_code_id`),
);

SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  title,
  COALESCE (
    COUNT(DISTINCT r.redeemed_code_id),
      0
   ) AS totalRewards,
  COALESCE (
    COUNT(DISTINCT ocm.user_id),
    0
   ) AS totalStudents,
  COALESCE (sum(r.points), 0) AS totalPoints
  FROM
  `organisation_classrooms` `t`
   LEFT OUTER JOIN classroom_redeemed_codes r ON (
   r.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
   AND r.inactive = 0
   AND (
    r.date_redeemed >= 1393286400
    OR r.date_redeemed = 0
   )
   )
   LEFT OUTER JOIN organisation_classrooms_myusers ocm ON (
   ocm.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
   )
   WHERE
    t.organisation_id =37383
   GROUP BY title
   ORDER BY t.classroom_id ASC
   LIMIT 10
```

-- EDIT --

OOPS! I hate SQL sometimes... I have made a big mistake, I am trying to count the number of STUDENTS in the **classroom_redeemed_codes** rather than the organisation_classrooms_myuser table. I'm really sorry I should have picked that up sooner?!

```
classroom_id | totalUniqueStudents
     16             1
     17             2
     46             1
     51             1
     52             1
```

There are 7 rows in the classroom_redeemed_codes table but as classroom_id 46 has two rows although with the same myuser_id (this is the student id) this should appear as one unique student.

Does this make sense? Essentially trying to grab the number of unique students in the classroom_redeemed_codes tables based on the myuser_id column.

e.g a classroom id 46 could have 100 rows in the classroom_redeemed_codes tables, but if it is the same myuser_id for each this should show the totalUniqueStudents count as 1 and not 100.

Let me know if this isn't clear....

-- update --
I have the following query which seems to work borrowed from a user below which seems to work... (my head hurts) i'll accept the answer again. Sorry for the confusion - I think I was just over thinking this somewhat

```
select crc.classroom_id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT crc.myuser_id) AS users,
    COUNT( DISTINCT crc.redeemed_code_id ) AS classRewards,
    SUM( crc.points ) as classPoints, t.title
  from classroom_redeemed_codes crc
       JOIN organisation_classrooms t
         ON crc.classroom_id = t.classroom_id 
        AND t.organisation_id = 37383
        where crc.inactive = 0
        AND ( crc.date_redeemed >= 1393286400
        OR crc.date_redeemed = 0 )
        group by crc.classroom_id
```

Comment: Does `COUNT(DISTINCT r.redeemed_code_id)` solve the problem?

Comment: Almost.. well I thought it did then I noticed an issue. The sqlfiddle above will give you my db structure.

Comment: Could you explain what's incorrect? Show the results you expect, and how the actual results are different.

Comment: no problem... i will do this now

Comment: The fields `classroom_id` and `myuser_id` from table `classroom_redeemed_codes` make me think they are a FK from table `organisation_classrooms_myusers`. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran by first doing a pre-query aggregate of your points per specific class, then used left-join to it.  I am getting more rows in the result set than your sample expected, but don't have MySQL to test/confirm directly.  However[here is a SQLFiddle of your query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a9f45/19)  By doing your query with sum of points, and having a Cartesian result when applying the users table, it is probably the basis of duplicating the points.  By pre-querying on the redeem codes itself, you just grab that value, then join to users.

```
SELECT
      t.classroom_id,
      title,
      COALESCE ( r.classRewards, 0 ) AS totalRewards,
      COALESCE ( r.classPoints, 0) AS totalPoints,
      COALESCE ( r.uniqStudents, 0 ) as totalUniqRedeemStudents,
      COALESCE ( COUNT(DISTINCT ocm.user_id), 0 ) AS totalStudents
   FROM
      organisation_classrooms t
         LEFT JOIN ( select crc.classroom_id,
                            COUNT( DISTINCT crc.redeemed_code_id ) AS classRewards,
                            COUNT( DISTINCT crc.myuser_id ) as uniqStudents,
                            SUM( crc.points ) as classPoints
                        from classroom_redeemed_codes crc
                           JOIN organisation_classrooms t
                              ON crc.classroom_id = t.classroom_id 
                              AND t.organisation_id = 37383
                        where crc.inactive = 0
                          AND ( crc.date_redeemed >= 1393286400
                           OR crc.date_redeemed = 0 )
                        group by crc.classroom_id ) r
            ON t.classroom_id = r.classroom_id

         LEFT OUTER JOIN organisation_classrooms_myusers ocm 
            ON t.classroom_id = ocm.classroom_id
   WHERE
      t.organisation_id = 37383
   GROUP BY 
      title
   ORDER BY 
      t.classroom_id ASC
   LIMIT 10
```

Comment: @Zabs, don't forget the checkmark if this worked as needed to close the question out.

Comment: My bad - this SQL does confuse me sometimes... I am trying to do the count on the classroom_redeemed_codes table.

REALLY SORRY! I should have noticed my mistake sooner

Comment: @Zabs, That IS what it does.  Look first at the inner query on it's own merits. It is doing on a per-classroom basis, both a count of distinct codes and how many points for the classroom.  Then it gets joined to all POSSIBLE classroomss via the left-join.  If you wanted counts PER CODE PER CLASS, that is slightly different... Please confirm and I can adjust.  Ex: Class "A" has 2 distinct codes with 17 and 30 points respectively?  Is that what you need?

Comment: @Zabs, revised query for unique students per class per the redeem codes table.

Comment: @Zabs, humbly appreciate it, but many better than I, and I too had to start somewhere and am still learning.

Answer (score 5):

You need sum(r.points) and a subquery in the left outer join see below

```
 SELECT
 t.classroom_id,
 title,
 COALESCE (
   COUNT(DISTINCT r.redeemed_code_id),
     0
  ) AS totalRewards,
 COALESCE(sum(r.points),0) AS totalPoints
,COALESCE(sum(T1.cnt),0) as totalStudents
 FROM
  `organisation_classrooms` `t`
left outer join (select classroom_id, count(user_id) cnt
                  from organisation_classrooms_myusers 
 group by classroom_id) T1 on (T1.classroom_id=t.classroom_id)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN classroom_redeemed_codes r ON (
  r.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
  AND r.inactive = 0
  AND (
   r.date_redeemed >= 1393286400
   OR r.date_redeemed = 0
  )
  )
  WHERE
   t.organisation_id =37383
  GROUP BY title
  ORDER BY t.classroom_id ASC
  LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Good call - I had already tried that (but forget to add it to the sql query on this page)

It doesn't quite work - if you run the query above in the sqlfiddle I created you will see the results..

e.g Classroom Blue shows totalPoints as 100 points, but this value should be 50 as there is only one entry in the classroom_redeemed_codes table for 50pts that belongs to this classroom_id.

Good shout though however.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the expected results and the actual results to highlight my problem

Comment: OK I fixed the query.  You need a subquery in the left outer join

Comment: Thanks - this fixes the totalPoints however the totalStudents value has now changed and is incorrect. (thanks for the subquery stuff that does help still)

Answer (score 4):

I simplified your query; there is no need to use `COALLESCE` together with `COUNT()` because `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`. For `SUM()` I prefer to use `IFNULL()` because it is shorter and more readable. The results displayed below contain only the data for `classroom_id` #16, #17 and #46 for easier comparison with the example provided in the question. The actual result sets are bigger and contain all the `classroom_id`s present in the tables. However, their presence is not needed to understand how and why it works.

```
SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  t.title,
  COUNT(DISTINCT r.redeemed_code_id) AS totalRewards,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ocm.user_id) AS totalStudents,
  IFNULL(SUM(r.points), 0) AS totalPoints
FROM `organisation_classrooms` t
  LEFT JOIN `classroom_redeemed_codes` r
    ON r.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
    AND r.inactive = 0
    AND (r.date_redeemed >= 1393286400 OR r.date_redeemed = 0)
  LEFT JOIN `organisation_classrooms_myusers` ocm
    ON ocm.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
WHERE t.organisation_id = 37383
GROUP BY t.classroom_id
ORDER BY t.classroom_id ASC
```

Let's try to split it in pieces and put them together after that. First, let's see what users are selected:

#### Query #1

```
SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  t.title,
  ocm.user_id
FROM `organisation_classrooms` t
  LEFT JOIN `organisation_classrooms_myusers` ocm
    ON ocm.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
WHERE t.organisation_id = 37383
ORDER BY t.classroom_id ASC
```

I removed the `classroom_redeemed_codes` table and it fields, removed `GROUP BY` and replaced the aggregate function `COUNT(ocm.user_id)` with `ocm.user_id` to see what users are selected.

The result show us this part of the query is correct:

```
classroom_id | title | user_id
-------------+-------+--------
16           | BLUE  | 2
16           | BLUE  | 1
17           | GREEN | 508835
17           | GREEN | 508826
46           | PINK  | NULL
```

There are 2 users in classroom #16, another 2 in #7 and none in class #46.
Putting back the `GROUP BY` clause will make it return the correct values (2, 2, 0) in the `totalStudents` column.

Let's check now the relationship with table `classroom_redeemed_codes`:

#### Query #2

```
SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  t.title,
  r.redeemed_code_id, r.points
FROM `organisation_classrooms` t
  LEFT JOIN `classroom_redeemed_codes` r
    ON r.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
    AND r.inactive = 0
    AND (r.date_redeemed >= 1393286400 OR r.date_redeemed = 0)
WHERE t.organisation_id = 37383
ORDER BY t.classroom_id ASC
```

The result is:

```
classroom_id | title | redeemed_code_id | points
-------------+-------+------------------+-------
16           | BLUE  | 7                | 50
17           | GREEN | 8                | 25
17           | GREEN | 9                | 75
46           | PINK  | 5                | 250
46           | PINK  | 6                | 100
```

Again, grouping by `classroom_id` will produce (1, 2, 2) in column `totalRewards` and (50, 100, 350) in column `totalPoints` which is correct.

The trouble starts when you want to combine these into a single query. No matter what kind of join you use, for the provided input you will get (2*1, 2*2, 1*2) rows for `classroom_id` having the values 16, 17 and 46 (in this order). The values I multiplied in parenthesis are the number of rows for each `classroom_id` in the first and in the query result set above.

#### Combined

Let' try the query that selects the rows before grouping them:

```
SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  t.title,
  r.redeemed_code_id, ocm.user_id, r.points
FROM `organisation_classrooms` t
  LEFT JOIN `classroom_redeemed_codes` r
    ON r.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
    AND r.inactive = 0
    AND (r.date_redeemed >= 1393286400 OR r.date_redeemed = 0)
  LEFT JOIN `organisation_classrooms_myusers` ocm
    ON ocm.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
WHERE t.organisation_id = 37383
ORDER BY t.classroom_id ASC
```

It returns this result set:

```
classroom_id | title | redeemed_code_id | user_id | points
-------------+-------+------------------+---------+-------
16           | BLUE  | 7                | 2       | 50          
16           | BLUE  | 7                | 1       | 50      <- *
-------------+-------+------------------+---------+-------
17           | GREEN | 8                | 508835  | 25
17           | GREEN | 8                | 508826  | 25      <- *
17           | GREEN | 9                | 508835  | 75
17           | GREEN | 9                | 508826  | 75      <- *
-------------+-------+------------------+---------+-------
46           | PINK  | 5                | NULL    | 250
46           | PINK  | 6                | NULL    | 100
```

I added horizontal rules to separate the rows that belongs to the same group when we add the `GROUP BY` clause. This is basically the way a `SQL` query with `GROUP BY` is executed, no matter the name of the actual software that implements it.

As you can see, for each classroom, it combines all the redeemed codes associated with the classroom with all the users associated with the classroom. If you add more users and redeemed codes for classrooms #16, #17 and #46 in your tables you will get a much larger result set.

The next step on the execution of a `GROUP BY` query is to produce a single row from each group you see above. There is no problem with columns `classroom_id` and `title`, they contain a single value in each group. For the columns `redeemed_code_id` and `user_id` your query counts distinct values and that works fine too. The problem is with the addition of `points`.
If you just `SUM()` them, you get a redeemed code added for each user_id in the group. If you use `SUM(DISTINCT points)` it is also wrong because it will ignore the duplicates even when they are different entries in table `classroom_redeemed_codes`.

What you want is to add `points` for `DISTINCT redeemed_code_id`. I marked on the above result set the rows you don't want.

This is not possible using this query because on calculation of the aggregate values each column is independent of the other. We need a query that selects the desired rows before grouping them.

### An Idea

We can try to add the missing columns (with `NULL` values) to the two simple queries above, `UNION ALL` them then select from this and `GROUP BY`.

First, let's be sure it selects what we need:

```
SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  t.title,
  NULL AS redeemed_code_id, ocm.user_id, NULL AS points
FROM `organisation_classrooms` t
  LEFT JOIN `organisation_classrooms_myusers` ocm
    ON ocm.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
WHERE t.organisation_id = 37383

UNION ALL

SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  t.title,
  r.redeemed_code_id, NULL AS user_id, r.points
FROM `organisation_classrooms` t
  LEFT JOIN `classroom_redeemed_codes` r
    ON r.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
    AND r.inactive = 0
    AND (r.date_redeemed >= 1393286400 OR r.date_redeemed = 0)
WHERE t.organisation_id = 37383

ORDER BY classroom_id
```

**Attention!** The `ORDER BY` clause applies to the `UNION`ed result set. If you want to order the rows of each `SELECT` (it doesn't help because `UNION` doesn't keep the order) you need to enclose that query in parenthesis and put the `ORDER BY` clauses there.

The result set looks great:

```
classroom_id | title | redeemed_code_id | user_id | points
-------------+-------+------------------+---------+-------
16           | BLUE  | NULL             | 1       | NULL
16           | BLUE  | NULL             | 2       | NULL
16           | BLUE  | 7                | NULL    | 50
-------------+-------+------------------+---------+-------
17           | GREEN | 8                | NULL    | 25
17           | GREEN | 9                | NULL    | 75
17           | GREEN | NULL             | 508826  | NULL
17           | GREEN | NULL             | 508835  | NULL
-------------+-------+------------------+---------+-------
46           | PINK  | 5                | NULL    | 250
46           | PINK  | 6                | NULL    | 100
46           | PINK  | NULL             | NULL    | NULL
```

Now we could put some parenthesis around the query above (strip `ORDER BY`) and use it in another query, grouping the data by `classroom_id`, counting the users and the redeemed codes and summing their points.

You will get a query that looks awful and, on your current database schema, crawls when your tables have several hundred rows. **This is why I will not write it here**.

**Attention!**
Its performance can be improved by adding the missing indexes to your tables, on the fields that appear in the `ON`, `WHERE`, `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses of the query.

It will bring a significant improvement but I won't rely very much on that. For really big tables (hundreds of thousands of rows) it will still crawl.

### Another Idea

We can also add `GROUP BY` on both **Query #1** and **Query #2** first and `UNION ALL` them after that:

```
SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  t.title,
  NULL AS totalRewards,
  COUNT(DISTINCT ocm.user_id) AS totalStudents,
  NULL AS totalPoints
FROM `organisation_classrooms` t
  LEFT JOIN `organisation_classrooms_myusers` ocm
    ON ocm.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
WHERE t.organisation_id = 37383
GROUP BY t.classroom_id

UNION ALL

SELECT
  t.classroom_id,
  t.title,
      COUNT(DISTINCT redeemed_code_id) AS totalRewards,
      NULL AS totalStudents,
      SUM(points) AS totalPoints
FROM `organisation_classrooms` t
  LEFT JOIN `classroom_redeemed_codes` r
    ON r.classroom_id = t.classroom_id
    AND r.inactive = 0
    AND (r.date_redeemed >= 1393286400 OR r.date_redeemed = 0)
WHERE t.organisation_id = 37383
GROUP BY t.classroom_id

ORDER BY classroom_id, totalRewards
```

This produces a nice result set:

```
classroom_id | title | totalRewards | totalStudents | totalPoints
-------------+-------+--------------+---------------+-------------
16           | BLUE  | NULL         | 2             | NULL
16           | BLUE  | 1            | NULL          | 50
17           | GREEN | NULL         | 2             | NULL
17           | GREEN | 2            | NULL          | 100
46           | PINK  | NULL         | 0             | NULL
46           | PINK  | 2            | NULL          | 350
```

This query can be embedded in another query that groups by `classroom_id` and `SUM()`s the total columns above to get the final result. But again, the final query is big and ugly and it
doesn't run very fast for large tables. And again, **this is the reason I don't write it here**.

### Conclusion

It can be done in a single query but it doesn't look good and it doesn't work well on large tables.

Regarding the performance, put `EXPLAIN` in front of your query then check the values in columns `type`, `key` and `Extra` of the result. See the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain-output.html) for explanation of the possible values of these columns, what to try to achieve and what to avoid.

Both queries I created on both ideas produce joins of type `range` or `ALL` and having `Using filesort` in column `Extra` (all these are slow). Using them as sub-queries in bigger queries will not improve the way they are execution, on the contrary.

I recommend you to **run the individual `SELECT` queries from the last code example as two separate queries**; they will return the odd and the even rows from the above result set. Then **combine their results into the client code**. It will run faster this way.

Comment: brilliant answer axiac although I used the method below as it seems more concise for what I need - but your post was brilliant, loved the detail A++

Comment: I've written it while I was building and running the queries using the data you posted. It works. I added the extra 'AND t.classroom_id IN (16, 17, 46)' condition to strip the results to avoid getting distracted by other rows and that affects the final result. However, my advice is to run two queries, one for users, the other for redeemed codes. The code is more clear this way; there is no reason to mix users and redeemed codes in the same query as long as they are unrelated entities.

Comment: I'd agree having the two queries is better, as it is part of a Yii query that ties into a Yii extension this is main reason for having this within the single query (as opposed to multiple queries). But your post was pure EPIC... many thanks

Comment: downvoted.. only because you appear to be fixated on the fact of the 3 specific classrooms, but not to the global of all POSSIBLE classes.  The OP only did sample data and obviously not an entire dump.  You can't rely on such.

Comment: @DRapp I explained I added that condition just for testing, to get a shorter result set. I also explained that I do not recommend computing everything in a big query because of poor performance. Removing a condition from the `WHERE` clause will make the performance even worse, don't you think? Does it look like I rely on that condition being present?

Comment: So noted, and I can't undo the downvote unless the answer is edited... but I'll hit a few upvotes on some other questions to bring back some rep votes for you :)

Comment: @DRapp I modified the answer, removed the filtering on `classroom_id` and explained in the introductory paragraph that the result sets show only the records from the OP's example for easier comparison. Indeed, having the condition there could mislead future users. Don't worry about the votes and points. :-)

Comment: plus one for keeping it civil :)